# Is there an easy way to integrate Salesforce with GoFormz?

Tags: integration

We are doing double the amount of work right now filling forms out in GoFormz and then documenting the information all over again in SalesForce.  I'm looking for help.  I am paying for both programs now and I cannot pay for a bridge between the two.  I know about Zapier.

Comment: Do you have any in-house developers? It's totally possible to DIY, but you're going to need some in-house expertise.

Comment: I will be the in-house expertise.  I am learning.

Comment: Well, you just need to figure out how you want it built. The way I see it, you can either build forms in salesforce, and have it automatically send the forms to GoFormz, or you can build the forms in GoFormz, and have the data sent to salesforce. The choice is yours, whichever you think will be easier.

Comment: you can build forms in SalesForce?  Looks like more research to be done.

Comment: Yes, GoFormz API allows you to create forms and update their values, so it's entirely possible to build everything inside Salesforce. This might save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes back, I posted a similar answer about [Wufoo](https://www.wufoo.com/) Salesforce integration [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161463/salesforce-webhook-for-wufoo-form-integration/161508#161508). I believe similar support is available from GoFormz and you can follow the same steps to get it done.

Basically, the idea is to create a REST Service in Salesforce and use it as a Webhook to POST the GoFormz form data from GoFormz to Salesforce.

I just checked the GoFormz site and Webhook support is there. I hope the above information will definitely help you to start the integration.

Comment: One could also create the forms in salesforce, and use triggers/Visualforce to send the data the other way, too.